# String Replace using C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have string which consist of a mobile number like "0887543232". I want to replace 0 with a country code. I have the country code variable. Below is my code where I am trying to replace the 0.

```
string mobile="0887543232"
string  countryCode= "+1"
int len = mobile.Length;
string mob = mobile.Substring(0, 1);
if (mob == "0")
{
    mobile = mobile.Replace(mob,countrycode);
}
```

Comment: Look at `if (mob == 0)`. What's the type of the `mob` variable? It's `string`. You're trying to compare a string with an integer... what do you expect that to do?

Comment: In their rush to get rep people solved your problem for you by providing various ways of doing what you're trying to do, yet you never actually stated what problem you are facing.

Comment: All answers should be downvoted:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want to replace zeros, you want to prepend the countrycode, you can use:

```
if (mobile.StartsWith("0"))
{
    mobile = countryCode + mobile.TrimStart('0');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about?

```
string mobile="0887543232";
string  countryCode= "+1";

if(!mobile.StartsWith(countryCode)){
mobile = (countryCode + mobile.TrimStart('0'));
}
```

This will only prepend the country code if the number does not have it already.